# Remove the line title from the JSON structure

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, spreadsheet

[image]

Here is a [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QGJU5FJVmKI3A5A3NFY-XQU7MlBOG0VmvUIZvx8Bitg/edit#gid=72338765) of my spreadsheet

```
//max CPC
var maxCPC = 3.00;
//min CPC
var minCPC = 0.50;
//percentage change down


function main() {
    var SPREADSHEET_URL = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QGJU5FJVmKI3A5A3NFY-XQU7MlBOG0VmvUIZvx8Bitg/edit#gid=72338765";

    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(SPREADSHEET_URL);
    var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Campaigns');
    var data = sheet.getRange("A:C").getValues();

    var test = parseData(data)
}


function isBlank(line) {
    return line[0].trim() === '' && line[1].trim() === '';
}


function parseData(data) {

    const output = {};
    var currentGroupName = '';

    data.forEach(function(line){
        if (isBlank(line)){
            return; 
        }

        if (line[0].trim().length > 1) {
            currentGroupName = line[0].trim();
        }

        output[currentGroupName] = output[currentGroupName] || {};

        output[currentGroupName][line[1]] = line[2];
    });

    return output;
}
```

This code allows me to reformat a Google-Spreadsheet into a JSON structure. I don't want to include the first line since it is the title line, but I don't know how to do that. How could I modify my code so that it works fine?

Comment: How about ignoring the header row when data is retrieved? So how about modifying from ``var data = sheet.getRange("A:C").getValues();`` to ``var data = sheet.getRange("A2:C").getValues();``?

Comment: to skip the first line you can use `data.slice(1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you aren't concerned about memory usage, this is a good candidate for using [ES2015 destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), which will let you break your `data` array into a new `header` array and a new `lines` array containing the array of lines you want.  Here is what your code might look like using that:

```
function parseData(data) {

    const output = {};
    var currentGroupName = '';
    [header, ...lines] = data;  // break data into the first item, 'header', and the rest of the items, 'lines'

    lines.forEach(function(line){
        if (isBlank(line)){
            return; 
        }

        if (line[0].trim().length > 1) {
            currentGroupName = line[0].trim();
        }

        output[currentGroupName] = output[currentGroupName] || {};

        output[currentGroupName][line[1]] = line[2];
    });

    return output;
}
```

However, if you don't want to copy your data array, you could also just include the `index` parameter in the [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Syntax) call inside of your `parseData` function and use it to skip the first line of data as you iterate through the lines:

```
function parseData(data) {

    const output = {};
    var currentGroupName = '';

    data.forEach(function(line, index){
        if (isBlank(line) || index === 0){
            return; 
        }

        if (line[0].trim().length > 1) {
            currentGroupName = line[0].trim();
        }

        output[currentGroupName] = output[currentGroupName] || {};

        output[currentGroupName][line[1]] = line[2];
    });

    return output;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a reason why most parsers include a question: "Does your file include headers?" (or some variation thereof)  However, if you will always have a header row guaranteed, you can change your parsing routine something like this:

```
function parseData(data) {

    const output = {};
    var currentGroupName = '';
    var skipLine = 1;

    data.forEach(function(line){
        if (isBlank(line)){
            return; 
        }
        if (skipLine == 1) {
            skipline = 0;
        }
        else {
            if (line[0].trim().length > 1) {
                currentGroupName = line[0].trim();
            }

            output[currentGroupName] = output[currentGroupName] || {};

            output[currentGroupName][line[1]] = line[2];
        } 
    });

    return output;
}
```